# Should I redesign my "events" table

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization

My system needs to store an append only log of events.  Currently I have a database table that stores all the relevant data in one table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `events` (
        `event_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        `event_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `event_timestamp` DATETIME,
        `group_id` VARCHAR(255),
        `person_id` VARCHAR(255),
        `client_id` VARCHAR(255),
        `name` VARCHAR(768),
        `result` VARCHAR(255),
        `status` VARCHAR(255),
        `logged_at` DATETIME,
        `severity` VARCHAR(255),
        `message` LONGTEXT,
        INDEX `event_type_index` (`event_type`),
        INDEX `event_timestamp_index` (`event_timestamp`),
        INDEX `group_id_index` (`group_id`),
        INDEX `person_id_index` (`person_id`),
        INDEX `client_id_index` (`client_id`),
        INDEX `name_index` (`name`),
        INDEX `result_index` (`result`),
        INDEX `status_index` (`status`),
        INDEX `logged_at_index` (`logged_at`),
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

But I've noticed that queries with multiple attributes in the WHERE clause are still slow.  For example:

```sql
SELECT
  count(e.event_id) as total
FROM events e
WHERE
  e.result='Success' AND
  e.event_type='some_silly_event' AND
  e.event_timestamp > '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

One solution would be to create an index like the following:

```sql
CREATE INDEX successful_silly_events
ON events (result,event_type,event_timestamp);
```

The downsides of this approach seem to be that creating the index would take a long time, and would only speed up this query.  If I create a different query on this table with different columns, I'm back to square one.

Would I have been better served by splitting the events table into multiple tables from the start?  For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `events` (
        `event_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `logged_at` DATETIME,
        `severity` VARCHAR(255),
        `message` LONGTEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY (event_id),
        INDEX `logged_at_index` (`logged_at`),
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `event_types` (
        `event_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `event_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY event_id REFERENCES events(event_id)
        INDEX `event_type_index` (`event_type`),
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `event_timestamps` (
        `event_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `event_timestamp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY event_id REFERENCES events(event_id)
        INDEX `event_timestamp_index` (`event_timestamp`),
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `event_groups` (
        `event_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `group_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY event_id REFERENCES events(event_id)
        INDEX `group_id_index` (`group_id`),
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

And so on for all the other event attributes which I would have normally indexed on the events table.  This way, I could construct a similar query:

```sql
SELECT
  count(e.event_id) as total
FROM events e
  LEFT JOIN event_results er ON e.event_id=er.event_id
  LEFT JOIN event_types ety ON e.event_id=et.event_id
  LEFT JOIN event_timestamps eti ON e.event_id=et.event_id 
WHERE
  er.result='Success' AND
  ety.event_type='some_silly_event' AND
  eti.event_timestamp > '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Would the resulting query be fast and not require full table scan?  If so, this seems like a better setup.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS as some have a potential solution ( `BITMAP INDEX` ) while others don't (eg `MySQL` )

Comment: It's unlikely that you will see improved performance with multiple tables, but the only sure way to tell is to test.

Comment: To evaluate suitable indexes a more comprehensive list of queries on this table is needed, which ones have important response time? Is there a any logical groupings on dates? On reducing table size, which fields in this table are really UTF8MB4? Are `status`, `result`, `severity`, `event_type` really just a small set of ENUMs? Are `group_id`, `person_id`, `client_id` a fairly static list that could be in a separate table? What MySQL version?

Comment: About how many records and gigabytes?  How often is it written to, and how often is it queried?  Do you need real-time access to the data, or would a delay be acceptable?

Answer (score 5):

`INDEX(result, event_type, event_timestamp)` obviates the need for `INDEX(result)` and `INDEX(result, event_type)`.

Blindly using `(255)` hurts indexes and queries.  Trim back to realistic limits.

Splitting up the table the way you suggested helps nothing and hurts most queries.  In particular, then you would not be able to effectively use the multiple indexes, nor would you be able to use a 'composite' index (since it would involve more than one table).  On the other hand, if your 'log' gets to be too huge, then such 'normalization' will drastically shrink the disk footprint.  This, itself, has some positive impact on performance.

Do *not* normalize 'continuous' values such as `timestamp`.  This severely hurts performance because it makes it impractical to have an index on a "range" value.

Don't use `LEFT` unless you need the 'right' table to be optional.  `LEFT` sometimes implies that the 'left' table *must* be scanned first.  In your example, that would lead to a full scan of `events`.

If you change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` (in the last example), then the Optimizer would pick among the tables to decide which one to start with.  This would be equivalent (but slower) than the original case of single-column indexes on the relevant columns.

"Low cardinality" columns (`status` and `result`) are virtually useless to index by themselves.  They can be effective when the first column of a 'composite' index.

Most tables have a limited number of queries that will realistically be applied.  If you are saying that your table begs for lots of different queries, then my advice is as follows:

- Monitor what queries people want.  Keep track of the *typical* combinations of columns.
- Implement a few 2- and 3-column indexes.
- Be sure to have the *first* column(s) in the index be column(s) that are tested (in `WHERE`) with `=`.  If there is also a "range" (as in your example with `timestamp`), then put it last.  (Punt on multiple range tests.)
- Remember that the order of `ANDing` things in `WHERE` does not matter, but the order of columns in an `INDEX` does.
- More on creating optimal indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

MySQL does not implement "bitmap" indexes; they are rarely worth the effort.  MySQL does implement "index merge intersect" (for `ANDs`) which is a clumsy way to simulate a composite index.  "index merge union" (for `ORs`) is sometimes handy for `OR`; but `UNION` is likely to be as good.

Yours seems like a "Data Warehouse" application.  The best speedup for such is to build and maintain [*Summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).  For your one example, a summary of daily counts broken down by `result` and `event_type` would be much smaller and much faster to query.  (10x speedup is quite possible.)  Furthermore, it is practical to have different indexes on the Summary table, thereby somewhat breaking the log jam you currently have.  (You would `SUM` the subtotals to get the total `COUNT`.)

Answer (score 2):

No, splitting the table into multiple tables the way you propose will not be helpful in your situation. Here are some tips that *will* help:

With InnoDB it is important to use short primary keys, because the whole table storage is organized around the primary keys, plus the secondary indexes refer to the target rows by primary key. Having huge relatively random primary keys can cause the table B-tree to get out of balance and worse, makes the secondary indexes unnecessarily large. So the first thing you can do to improve performance is change your event table to have an auto-generated primary key that is an integer of the appropriate size.

Second, indexes only help if they significantly reduce the number of rows to scan. Having what is called a "low cardinality" index, which means an index where the number of possible values is small relative to the number of rows in the table, is a waste because it is almost never useful but it takes up time and space to maintain. You probably are not getting any benefit out of indexes on `event_type`, `status`, or `result` by themselves.

Similarly, indexes only help when the column is used as an exact match or the column has a natural ordering and is used in a range match. Combined indexes should have the columns in order from least specific to most specific and again will only be used to the extent that the columns, *in order* starting with the first one, are the target of exact matches (except the last column can be a range).

I expect that all of your queries are going to be including a time range of either `event_timestamp` or `logged_at`, so really those are the only columns (except the primary key, of course) that need to be indexed, because no other index will work in combination with those. However, if you commonly filter the results by exact match with 1 or 2 columns, then it might make sense to have a combined index putting those columns first and the timestamp last. Of course, you have to use the right timestamp in the index and only one timestamp. Combining `event_timestamp` and `logged_at` in one index is worse than useless.

It will also help to build some kind of *data warehouse* strategy to keep that table from getting ridiculously large. Think about the kind of queries you need on events that happened a month or a year ago and how often you need them, and then move the data somewhere else (possibly summarizing it) on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Rick James. It is highly likely the `VARCHAR` especially on the PK is slowing down the query.

`event_id` as well as other `*_id` columns should be of type INT (or similar).

> The downsides of this approach seem to be that creating the index would take a long time, and would only speed up this query. If I create a different query on this table with different columns, I'm back to square one.

I would do this circumvent table locking on a live table:

- Create a new table: `events_new`
- Change `event_id` in `events_new` to int
- Copy events data to events_new table
- Rename events to events_bak (super fast)
- Rename events_new to events (super fast)

In fact I would do this to other related tables that also have `VARCHAR` type for PK (group_id, person_id, client_id).

Answer (score 0):

You already know the answer is,

One solution would be to create an index like the following:

CREATE INDEX successful_silly_events
ON events (result,event_type,event_timestamp);

Just do it.